# Flexslider stopped working. Firebug shows TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: function, animation, slide, typeerror, flexslider

I'm developing a single page wordpress website for our client. In that i have used flexslider in header section and some other jquery plugins. All of them were working till today morning but now I found that the flexslider stopped working. 

I'm not able to find out the reason. 
Please help me to solve this issue as I have to submit this project today.

Error Found on Firebug Console:
TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

animation: "slide"

- /Demo/website/ (line 34)

How can i fix this? Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery.flexslider.js is not loading. Try removing the `defer` keyword from or add  `type="text/javascript"` and see if it works. Your current source:

```
<script defer src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Demo/allabout/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

I suggest you try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Demo/allabout/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where did you change this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. hope this will work.

```
(function($) {
$(window).load(function(){
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
--------- YOUR CONFIGURATIONS --------
});
});
})(jQuery);
```