# Flexslider not working with carabiner - codeigniter library

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, flexslider, carabiner

There is some problem with flexslider and codeigniter's carabiner library. I am combining all the js and css on my website but flexslider is not being combined. If its included seperately it works fine. The error i am having is

> $(...).flexslider is not a function

Here is what i am doing with carabiner which is not working.

```
$js = array(
    array('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', '', TRUE, FALSE),      
    array('js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', '', TRUE, FALSE) );

$this->carabiner->js($js);
```

If i simply include the flexslider script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

that works fine. I guess it may be due to the `type="text/javascript"` as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103424/flexslider-stopped-working-firebug-shows-typeerror-flexslider-is-not-a)

Is there any way i can combine the flexslider js with other js files in carabiner ?

Comment: hi can you put config settings for carabiner library

Comment: Here are the carabiner config flags:
`$config['script_dir'] = 'assets/'; 
$config['style_dir'] = 'assets/';
$config['cache_dir'] = 'assets/cache/';
$config['dev'] = FALSE;
$config['combine'] = TRUE;
$config['minify_js'] = TRUE;
$config['minify_css'] = TRUE;
$config['force_curl'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mention the solution i have done to encounter this issue, that may help some one out there.

There were too many of the js files which were being combined and minified and flexslider js was almost at the end. I have just changed the place of the flexslider to some what right after the jquery lib, which worked like a charm :)

Don't know the exact reason why it was not working at the original place but what i assume that could be because of some js conflict with any other js file while minifying and combining.

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to set base uri in config check in  carabiner.php config file you will find

```
//$config['base_uri'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

just remove comment and put your site address. 2nd way you can set carabiner config in controller

```
$config = array('base_uri'=>base_url());
$this->carabiner->config($config);
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: The file is being combined with other js file (means the path is fine), but for some reasons it is not triggering, I can see the file added in the combined assets, that's why i am getting `TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function` error